# Неудачное удаление python3.8 ubuntu20.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, ethernet

Всем привет. Случайно удалил python3.8 в ubuntu 20.04 , после этого кое-как восстановил работоспособность, но вот сеть через кабель работать не хочет(не видит сетевой кабель). В пк установлен wifi модуль - работает как и прежде. Подскажите как устранить проблему.
Модель сетевого адаптера: Intel® I211-AT, 1 x Gigabit LAN Controller.
Вывод ifconfig:

```
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:44:71:c9:3c  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp8s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 04:92:26:d9:b1:c8  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0xfc400000-fc41ffff  

enp8s0:avahi: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 169.254.11.22  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 169.254.255.255
        ether 04:92:26:d9:b1:c8  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        device memory 0xfc400000-fc41ffff  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Локальная петля (Loopback))
        RX packets 1392  bytes 128592 (128.5 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1392  bytes 128592 (128.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp6s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.107  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::d7ad:ea30:2c8:6075  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 74:40:bb:57:3c:33  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 50624  bytes 58359660 (58.3 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 21416  bytes 4290648 (4.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: `mii-tool enp8s0` и `dhclient enp8s0` не работают?

Comment: `enp8s0: no link` , `cmp: EOF on /tmp/tmp.msNfLifFA6 which is empty`

Comment: Когда использовал dhclient enp8s0 - он попытался ее включить, но не смог

Comment: Тогда переустанови через apt все пакеты связанные с питоном. Ну или переустанови. Хз что быстрее.

Comment: Уже переустановил все пакеты, а переустановить ОС - не вариант, слишком долго(